# multiple Region/State in configuration

Tags: system.xml, system-configuration, regions

How to get multiple Region/State in Configuration in the same tab.

```
`<region_id translate="label">
                            <label>Region/State</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </region_id>`
```

I have tried above code in two different groups and same field, but for the  first field its showing dropdown at the time entering values and after saving its showing as textbox. Second group field working normally.

**Note**: both are same country(US) Region/States.

Please help me on how to maintain two Region/State in fields in same tab in `system->Configuration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this answer here it gives you a hint about how it work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373364/3531064

> The restriction of one pair to a page is a bit of a roadblock. I am writing my own source instead

I think you have to make your own pair configuration, duplicating the original one including JavaScript part.

---

*I am looking on a `1.12` EE but this is probably similar to other versions.*

In `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/js.phtml`
If you take a look `around line 80` you have a class called `originModel`.
In this class Magento is updating `region_id` field with `country_id` base on configuration nodes name directly `<country_id translate="label">` and `<region_id translate="label">` and the configuration inputs with CSS class `counties` set with `<frontend_class>countries</frontend_class>`
I suggest you to take a look how it work  here with this element that you can duplicate this.

Comment: `duplicating the original one including JavaScript part`, give some shadow on this

Comment: Sorry what does "give some shadow on this" means ? Do you need more details on how to do that ?

Comment: yes, the details of how to duplicate the region/state pair configuration and modifying javascript

Comment: OK no problem I update my answer

Comment: So do i need to copy and replace with `regiond_id` as `region_id1` and `country_id` as `country_id1` and using the same elements `region_id1` & `country_id1` in `system.xml`?

Comment: Please note that I have not tested that solution but looking at the code logic yes that is it ;)